# How to display a form inside another form like Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interface, interface-builder

How does Visual Studio and other similar programs display a form in their IDE?
Is it possible to achieve the same or a similar effect using C# or VB.NET?

Please see the picture below to get what I mean.

[image: Visual Studio IDE with a form in design view]

Comment: Do you mean generally displaying forms within a parent window (i.e MDI style interface) or displaying a form within the designer window for you to manipulate?

Comment: @Paolo: I'm referring to displaying a form in the designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about hosting a Winforms editor in your code, it is entirely possible and is actually built in to the .NET framework!

The Essence is the `IDesignerHost` interface.  The whole system is complicated, but can be done (I have done it in production code for runtime layout configuration editing).  There is a sample of code from Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;813808).

I'm sure if you search fir 'IDesignerHost' you'll find enough reference material to figure it out.

Comment: Perfect. Now I know it's possible, I'll add it to my toolbox for any project that might require I do something of that sort. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you speaking about UI creating tools?
Refer to http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/ - SharpDevelop for deep dive. It's open sourse, so you'll be able to find out more details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a multiple document interface (MDI) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx for more info.

Comment: I'm sorry but no, I'm not talking about an MDI here. I know perfectly how to create an MDI interface.